# Flutter Firestore understanding joins

Tags: firebase, join, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am doing this in Flutter, with a Firebase database, using the Firestore packages in Flutter. **I would like to know how a join is done in noSQL (or more specifically, in Flutter-Firestore)**

This is what my database looks like:

```
users: {
     U1: {
         name: 'Peter',
         surname: 'Jensen'
     },
     U2: {
         name: 'Marry',
         surname: 'Kown'
     },
     ...
}

groups: {
     G1: {
         name: 'Group 1'
     },
     G2: {
         name: 'Group 2'
     },
     ...
}

members: {
     M1: {
         userId: U1,
         groupId: G1
     },
     M2: {
         userId: U1,
         groupId: G2
     },
     M3: {
         userId: U2,
         groupId: G1
     },
     ...
}
```

Now how do I do a join to get something like this:

```
members: {
     M1: {
         userId: {
             name: 'Peter',
             surname: 'Jensen'
         },
         groupId: {
             name: 'Group 1'
         }
     },
     M2: {
         userId: {
             name: 'Peter',
             surname: 'Jensen'
         },
         groupId: {
             name: 'Group 2'
         }
     },
     M3: {
         userId: {
             name: 'Marry',
             surname: 'Kown'
         },
         groupId: {
             name: 'Group 1'
         }
     },
     ...
}
```

Do I do:

```
const users = await Firestore.instance.collection('users').getDocuments();
const groups = await Firestore.instance.collection('groups').getDocuments();
const members = await Firestore.instance.collection('members').getDocuments();

...manually loop through everything and assign everything myself
```

(I need to add more text because I have 'mostly code'): I would assume the above would use of a lot of query data in Firebase, so I can't see how this would be a good idea. I actually just want to see **in what groups is a user a in**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have groups and members, I'd typically store the follow data:

- A list of users in a `users` collection.
- For each user I'd keep their properties *and* a list of the group IDs of the groups they're a member of.
- A list of groups in a `groups` collection.
- For each group I'd keep their properties

Note that you could model the nested list as a subcollection, but typically this is not needed. With the above model you can easily find what groups a user is part of, even even do a query for users who are part of a certain group with an `array-contains` clause.

To get a list of the properties of the group for a specific user, you'll indeed need to load that user, and their groups separately. This is normal with many NoSQL databases, and not necessarily as slow as you may expect. But if performance is not good enough, you can consider duplicating some data to reduce the need for joins.  It all depends on your needs, and unlike in relational data models, NoSQL is not dogmatic about such things.

To learn more about this topic:

- read [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/)
- watch [Getting to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! And especially the learn more part!

Comment: One thing I realize now I forgot to mention, which might affect your answer. Is that I want to add an `admin: true/false` property to the `member` collection. So with the groups in the members table, you need to somehow store the user's admin property as well (not just the group ID in an array)